# Byte Swap and padding left over space with 0's in C

Tags: c, byte, padding, swap

My program is supposed to switch the nth byte to the mth position, this is what I have so far:

```
        unsigned int x = 12456812; 
        int xn = x;
        int xm = x;

          int mask = 0;
          int mask_m = 0xFF << (m << 3) ;
          int mask_n = 0xFF << (n << 3);

        xn = x >> (n << 3);
        xn = xn & 0xFF;

        xm = x >> (m << 3) ;
        xm = xm & 0xFF;




        mask = (mask_m | mask_n)  ^ 0xFFFFFFFF;

        int x_swapped = (x & mask) | (xm << (n <<3)) | (xn << (m <<3));

        printf("switch: %d\n", x_swapped);
```

My program returns 1293932, which is very close to the intended result, but it needs the padding of 0's after the first byte. (see example)

```
Original base10 number:
    12456812 (          1011 1110 0001 0011 0110 1100) 

Program returns: 
    1293932  (0001 0111 1011 1110            0110 1100) 
(space intentionally left blank, for demonstration purposes) 


Byte swapped number (objective): 
   331219052 (0001 0111 1011 1110 0000 0000 0110 1100)
```

As you can see by the example, the shift isn't padding 0's but is swapping bytes.

Sorry for bad english

Comment: Use `uint32_t` for all numbers. Especially do not use *signed* `int` ever for bitwise operations.

Comment: Also the example is very unclear.

Comment: Sorry about the example issue, it has been fixed now, the program swaps out the bytes correctly but does not leave 0's in it's place

Comment: @4386427 the 0001 0111 comes from the swapped 2nd byte

Comment: The description doesn't match the example. The first description says to switch the n:th byte to the m:th position (leaving it unclear what what value to assign to the n:th position). However, in your example two bytes are copied leaving zeroes. I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the byte swap in a function and return the swapped value.

Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int swap_byte_n_and_m(unsigned int x, unsigned int n, unsigned int m)
{
                                            // Example x=0x00be136c, n=3, m=1
  unsigned int mask_n = 0xFF << (n << 3);   // mask_n = 0xff000000
  unsigned int mask_m = 0xFF << (m << 3);   // mask_m = 0x0000ff00
  unsigned int data_n = x & mask_n;         // data_n = 0x00000000
  unsigned int data_m = x & mask_m;         // data_m = 0x00001300
  x = x & ~mask_n & ~mask_m;                // x      = 0x00be006c
  if (n>m)
  {
    data_n = data_n >> ((n-m) << 3);        // data_n = 0x00000000
    data_m = data_m << ((n-m) << 3);        // data_m = 0x13000000
  }
  else
  {
    data_n = data_n << ((m-n) << 3);
    data_m = data_m >> ((m-n) << 3);
  }
  x = x | data_n | data_m;                  // x      = 0x13be006c
  return x;
}

int main(void)
{
  unsigned int x = 12456812;
  printf("Before swap : %12u - 0x%08x\n", x, x);
  x = swap_byte_n_and_m(x, 3, 1);
  printf("After swap  : %12u - 0x%08x\n", x, x);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Before swap :     12456812 - 0x00be136c
After swap  :    331219052 - 0x13be006c
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way :

```
// n and m should be between 0 and 3
unsigned int swap_byte_to_from(unsigned int x, unsigned int n, unsigned int m)
{
    unsigned char tmp[4];

    memcpy(tmp, &x, sizeof(int));
    x = 0;
    int i = 4;
    while (i--)
        x |= ((i == n) ? tmp[m] : (i == m) ? tmp[n] : tmp[i]) << (i << 3);
    return x;
}
```